# PHP Variables in dataLayer

Tags: php, data-layers, google-datalayer, data-layer

I am new to PHP and dataLayer but I have the below code which includes a dataLayer with PHP code. I want to use the datalayer variables to map them to google tag manager and would like to use the PHP variables available in the below code. What I would like to populate from the PHP variables are as below.

Name, Price, Category and Quantity to get populated from the PHP variables to the data layer structure.

Also, it should get all the product variables similarly depending on how many are there on the page where this code is getting loaded.

Also, want the transactionTotal to be populated which is the sum of all the prices of the individual product prices.

```
var cartItemMap = new Object();
    var cartItem1 = null;
    var cartItem2 = null;
    var cartItem3 = null;
    var cartItem4 = null;
    var cartItem5 = null;
    var cartItem6 = null;
    var cartItem7 = null;
    var cartItem8 = null;
    var cartItem9 = null;
<?php
    $size = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key => $pro){ 
        $size = $size + 1;
    }
    $i = 1;
    foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key => $pro){ 

        if($size > 9){
            $size = $size -1;
        }
        else{
?>

dataLayer = [{
    'transactionId': Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
    'transactionTotal': 11.99,
    'transactionTax': 1.29,
    'transactionShipping': 5,
    'transactionProducts': [{
        'sku': 121212,
        'name': "Test",
        'category': "Testing Category",
        'price': 33,
        'quantity': 1
    },{
        'sku': 'AA1243544',
        'name': 'Socks',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'price': 9.99,
        'quantity': 2
    }]
}];

if("<?php echo $pro['product_name'] ?>" != ''){
    cartItem<?php echo $i ?> = new Object();

    cartItem<?php echo $i ?>.productName = "<?php echo $pro['product_name'] ?>";
    cartItem<?php echo $i ?>.productPrice = "<?php echo $pro['product_price'] ?>";
    cartItem<?php echo $i ?>.productQuantity = <?php echo $pro['product_quantity'] ?>;
    cartItem<?php echo $i ?>.productCategory = "<?php echo $pro['product_category'] ?>";
    cartItemMap[<?php echo $key ?>] = cartItem<?php echo $i ?>;
}
<?php
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: If you find yourself nubering variable names, then you should perhaps be considering using an array or collection object instead

Comment: I completely do not have any idea on how to do it. Please help/explain.

Comment: Your code and problem is hard to follow. Where is your "Data Layer" in this and what are you attempting to do?

Comment: My dataLayer is:

dataLayer = 
[{ 'transactionId': Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
'transactionTotal': 11.99, 
'transactionTax': 1.29, 
'transactionShipping': 5, 
'transactionProducts': 
[{ 
'sku': 121212, 
'name': "Test", 
'category': 
"Testing Category", 
'price': 33, 
'quantity': 1 
},{ 
'sku': 'AA1243544', 
'name': 'Socks', 
'category': 'Apparel', 
'price': 9.99, 
'quantity': 2 }] }];

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cartItems = [
        <?php foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key => $pro): ?>
        {
            productName: "<?= $pro['product_name']; ?>",
            productPrice: "<?= $pro['product_price']; ?>",
            productQuantity: "<?= $pro['product_quantity']; ?>",
            productCategory: "<?= $pro['product_category']; ?>"
        },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    ];
</script>
```

This creates an array (cartItems) of objects (cartItem)

Comment: Hi Sepultura,
The code is working Thanks. I now want to generate a random number for each of the products in the array and also i want the transaction total in to a different variable on top of the array (I mean not in the array) to sum up the total value (product1 Price + product1 Price ...)

Comment: I think you can easily figure that out by yourself, I'm not here to write code for you sorry.

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for your help. Will try it myself.

Comment: Hey, I have been trying to get that but unable to do so.
I have added the below line of code. It is only working within the array but our side of array, it is not working. I think I am missing the syntax or some other problem. any suggestions please.

transactionTotal: "<?= $subTotal; ?>",

Comment: @kishoremcp If his answer worked you should accept it and upvote.